# response.setContentType() always trim the space between "; charset"?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.20, HttpServlet

my servlet code are as followings :-

```
response.setContentType("application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

but each time i will got the content type as :

```
application/xml;charset=utf-8
```

which is without the space between " ; ".

May i know how to bypass the space being trimmed?

Is there anyway to do so (eg : modify the servet-api.jar)?

Comment: Why is so important to keep space between semicolon and charset?

Answer (score 2):

It could be happening in Tomcat, in a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat, in a proxy, a firewall or somewhere in the client-side stack.  It is probably impossible to stop whatever is doing this.

But it should not matter.  The HTTP standard says that there is optional whitespace after the semicolon.  *Your client-side code should work whether the space is present or not*.